# Is it possible to make a two way connection between two cells are in two different sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to connect two of the cells between 2 Excel sheets, as well update both, if data has been entered in either of two cells.

- Cell A4 in Sheet 1.
- Cell B7 in Sheet 2.

Suppose, if 100 is entered in cell A4 in Sheet 1, then B7 in Sheet 2 should be updated with 100.

And if 80 is in cell B7 in Sheet 2, then cell A4 in sheet 1 should be 80 also.

I am using both version Excel 2013 & 2016.

Comment: This will require vba in a two worksheet_change events

Answer (score 3):

If you want a Dynamic link between Cells or Ranges of Cells, between Worksheets or even the Workbooks, for both way data entry, then VBA is the only solution.

You need to use the following VBA code in both the Sheets:

**How it works:**

- Either press **A**lt+F11 or Right click the Sheet **T**Ab.
- Click View Code from the popup menu.
- Copy and Paste both in VB editor for 
  respected Sheets.
- Save the Workbook as **M**acro Enabled.

---

**In Sheet 1:**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then
   If Target = Range("A4") Then
      Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B7").Value = Target.Value
   End If
End If

End Sub
```

---

**In Sheet 2:**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B7")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target = Range("B7") Then
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value <> Target.Value Then
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value = Target.Value
    End If
  End If
End If

End Sub
```

---

**NB:**

- Code in Sheet 2 will update the Sheet 1 if the values in both cells are not similar.
- If you don't need this, *simply remove the If statement line.*

Comment: I haven't done VBA in years, so I'm having trouble following how this works (and don't have ready access to Excel to test it and see what happens).  My read of the question is that the entry of a new value in either cell triggers update of both cells to the new value.  What is the trigger here that causes the new value to be recognized?  It seems like the sequence that Excel runs the two macros would always cause the same cell to be recognized as having the "right" value.  Is it that the entry causes only that sheet's macro to run?  Also, why don't both macros need to be the same (reversed)?

Comment: It's between `Sheet1A4` and `Sheet2B7`, What the Macro does, if U enter any value in `Sheet1A4` it updates `Sheet2B7` with the same value and the vise-versa.  It's what the `TWO WAY CONNECTION`. Just now I've tested again, it's works successfully for me,, U also test will work.

Comment: This can not be correct as it changes value of A4 and B7 respectively, unconditionally where ever a change is made in either sheet. For example, if you enter "Oh, no!" in **A1** (or any other cell) of either worksheet, the text "Oh, no!" appears in `Sheet1.A4` and `Sheet2.B7`

Comment: @TomBrunberg. now I've modified the code for both sheets and it's not considering any value entered in either of the Worksheet, as you have pointed out  **"Oh no!"** in `A1` or anywhere not updating either `Sheet1.A4` or `Sheet2.B7`. Excel updating the said cell from bot ways, if value written by user in either of the cells only. *THANKS , you prompted the mistake !*

Comment: You fixed the issue I pointed out and it now works when the two cells are edited as single cells (which was asked for), so I removed my dv. But there is still a problem if a range of cells are copied over one of the special cells. `Runtime error '13'; Type mismatch`. F.ex. select d1:d10, Ctrl-C and paste to A1:A10 in Sheet1 or B1:B10 in Sheet2.

Comment: Okay, soon I'll modify the code for RANGE, Have nice day.