# Excel: 2-way linkage for cells in separate workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, links

I am brand new, and not sure if I'm asking this correctly. I have an excel spreadsheet that I want to share with a client so we can both edit and update its information. However, I only want to share a section, or perhaps only one Worksheet because I have multiple different accounts on there that are not his. I don't want to have to update and edit two separate workbooks. What I'm hoping to do is create a 2-way link between the workbook I share with him, and my current one so that when a change is made on one it automatically updates on the other one, and vise versa.

A previous post helped me to do this between worksheets, and I love it (thanks Christofer Weber it works great). I realize it will require VBA, I just can't figure it out. Any ideas? I was just hoping to modify the current VBA being used for the worksheets.

Current one

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("A2:D5")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets(1).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target
    Sheets(2).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target
    Sheets(3).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

This is what I have so far, but I know that the top line is not correct.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("A2:D5")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Workbooks("Test excel workbook 1 - macro.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target
    Workbooks("Test excel workbook 2 - macro.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You may [Check this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1278626/is-it-possible-to-make-a-two-way-connection-between-two-cells/1278676#1278676) what   you need to do instated of Cell use Workbook references!

Answer (score 2):

I've tested this out, and I think it should be enough to help you along. But here are some things that I noticed.

First thing to note is that the `Intersect` method doesn't work if you're comparing ranges in different worksheets per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640397/runtime-error-1004-method-intersect-of-object-global-failed). You weren't explicitly doing that here, but I think that it's wise to specify which worksheet(s) you're working with instead of allowing VBA to implicitly decide for you.

Second thing is this line as an example:

```
Workbooks("Test excel workbook 1 - macro.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target
```

I personally think it's weird to be setting the value of one range to be another range instead of setting it to be the *value* of the other range, which would look like this instead:

```
Workbooks("Test excel workbook 1 - macro.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value
```

Here's the code I came up with:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const filePath As String = "C:\some\file\path\otherthing.xlsm"
    Dim otherwb As Workbook
    Dim otherws As Worksheet
    Dim thisws As Worksheet
    Dim rangeIntersection As Range

    'this will allow opening the other workbook without
    'displaying the white UI
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'setting a reference to this worksheet
    Set thisws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'opens an unopened workbook or it will simply set a reference
    'to this workbook if it's already opened
    Set otherwb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    'just chose a random worksheet
    Set otherws = otherwb.Worksheets(1)
    'doing the intersection
    Set rangeIntersection = _
        Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), _
        thisws.Range("A2:D5"))

    If Not rangeIntersection Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        otherws.Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    'uncomment this if you do want to close the wb at the end
'    otherwb.Save
'    otherwb.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The default member of Range forwards calls without parameters to the Value property, so Target.value is redundant. But I agree that it's nice to have it there for clarity.

Comment: Code looks good. Needless to say, this has to be in both sheets, reversed, for it to be a 2-way link. Since he is opening your file, the save & close should be used, and the code password protected. Maybe even an error handler that closes the other WB no matter what.

Comment: I know that writing `MyRange.Value` is redundant, but I think that we can agree that explicitly assigning the values is better for readability and easier for someone else to interpret.