# Two-way connection between multiple cells and across multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, cells

I am looking to make a 2-way connection across 2 worksheets so that I only have to change the entry on one sheet for it to be changed on the other and vice versa.

I found a good explanation here (I am just starting out with VBA so was very happy it worked without me having to change much!):
[Is it possible to make a two way connection between two cells](https://superuser.com/questions/1278626/is-it-possible-to-make-a-two-way-connection-between-two-cells)

It shows how to do it with one cell to another but how can I do it with a few different cells? for example:

> Sheet 1 cell A2 = Sheet 2 cell B3 (and vice versa)
>       Sheet 1 cell A4 = Sheet 2 cell B5 (and vice versa)
>       Sheet 1 cell A6 = Sheet 2 cell B7 (and vice versa)

The cells I am applying this to also contain data validation, but the code in the link above still seemed to work fine with it, on one set of cells anyway.

EDIT:
Someone here suggested code (though the comment seems to have gone now) I added my specific cells/sheets but I'm not sure if I populated it correctly as it gave me an error message:

> Runtime error 1004, method 'range of object' worksheet failed

The code with my specific cells etc. added for sheet 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target1 As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target1, Range("F9:F12")) Is Nothing Then  
      Worksheets("sheet 2").Range("F" & Target.Row + 1).Value = Target1.Value  
End If

End Sub`
```

and for sheet 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target2 As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target2, Range("F6:F9")) Is Nothing Then  
      Sheets("sheet 1").Range("F" & Target2.Row - 1).Value = Target2.Value  
End If

End Sub
```

A bit more information about the specifics, in case this is what might be causing issues.

I want:
sheet 1 F9 to match sheet 2 F6
sheet 1 F12 to match sheet 2 F9

They all contain data validation lists that mirror the corresponding cell.

They are merged with other cells:
sheet 1 - F9:H10
sheet 1 - F12:H13
sheet 2 - F6:G7
sheet 2 - F9:G10

Comment: sorry, I got an error message: Runtime error 1004 Method 'range of object' worksheet failed, so wasn't sure if I was editing the cell ranges correctly. It highlights the IF statement:

 `Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target1 As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target1, Range("F9:12")) Is Nothing Then
      Worksheets("GEDF SEDF Rates").Range("F" & Target.Row + 1).Value = Target1.Value
End If

End Sub`

ultimately, I want to make sheet 1 cell F9 match with sheet 2 cell F6, and Sheet 1 cell F12 match with Sheet 2 cell F9. have I made the range too vague with just a column ref?

Comment: [edit] your post to include the code you've tried and the problems you're having. The method in the linked answer works, and should work if duplicated. We can't tell what you're doing wrong without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: okay, I've added the code I was given with my specific cells added - hopefully easier to read now! and a bit more information about the cells involved in case that influences the code needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the module "sheet 1" put this code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  On Error GoTo eh
  If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F9,F12")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet 2").Range("F" & Target.Row - 3).Value = Target.Value
eh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description, , "Error in Worksheet_Change event, sheet 1"
  End If
End Sub
```

In the module "sheet 2" this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  On Error GoTo eh
  If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F6,F9")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").Range("F" & Target.Row + 3).Value = Target.Value
eh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description, , "Error in Worksheet_Change event, sheet 2"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing, it works! Thank you so much! Now I've really got the bug about learning how to understand this better!