# Connect several sheets in excel to update both ways

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I hope you can help. I have the same table in separate sheets (up to 12 sheets) and I want to be able to make a change in either sheet and it mirrors in all the other sheets (without having to CTRL and select sheets). I found a VBA but only works for 1 cell between 2 sheets and I cannot manage to apply it to a table within several sheets. Could anyone kindly help ?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If UCase(Sh.Name) = "SHEET1" Or UCase(Sh.Name) = "SHEET2" Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                If UCase(Target.Parent.Name) = "SHEET1" Then
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = Target
                Else
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = Target
                End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I also found this other solution but again could not apply it to my needs:

[Is it possible to make a two way connection between two cells are in two different sheets?](https://superuser.com/questions/1278626/is-it-possible-to-make-a-two-way-connection-between-two-cells-are-in-two-differe)

Thank you :)

Comment: Why do you need a workbook consisting up to 12 absolutely identical sheets?

Comment: excellent question, the worksheets will filter the months of the main worksheet. unfortunately the people i set this sheet for are too lazy to filter themselves everytime they work on the sheet and wants separate tabs for each months with a 2 way updates between each sheets.

Comment: Oh! Now your task becomes much clearer. So, you have collected real data in one long general sheet. To see and, if necessary, change the data for a particular month, just apply a filter. Lazy users want 12 month tabs instead of a filter. You agree to place the filtering results in separate sheets. Now users want to not only view, but also edit the filtering results. Are you trying to reconcile these changes with the main table so as not to lose the integrity?

Comment: yes that is the issue. what they want is that if they make a change to the main sheet it reflects in the respective sheets but if they make a change in let's say October sheet, it reflects on the main sheet. The reason I'm asking to update every other sheet is to avoid creating conflit where A1 will be different in every sheet.

Comment: How about taking away their ability to make changes to the main table? Just hide this sheet from users. All changes are made to separate tables. In this case, the general sheet is [**easily recreated from the data on separate sheets**](https://www.google.com/search?q=power+query+combine+multiple+sheets+into+one&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&bih=881&dpr=1).

Comment: The task you describe is not as simple as it might seem. The fact is that if cell A2 on the sheet "January" corresponds to cell A2 of the main sheet, then A2 on the sheet "February" can be A147 or A514 or somewhere else in the main table. Finding an exact match of cell addresses to change synchronously is not a trivial task.

Comment: regards taking away the ability to change the main sheet, i thought about that but they still want to be able to make the change anywhere they want..

regards the second part, i would be using the same exact table in all the sheet so A2 will be the same data in all the sheet, but if A2 refers to an event in january, it will be filtered out in the other months tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's formulate the problem a little differently:

*Let any change on any sheet of the workbook make all other sheets receive the same change.*

In this case, we do not need to analyze the addresses of the cells that have changed. We simply transfer the content of the changed sheet to all other sheets:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim oUsedRange As Range
    Set oUsedRange = Sh.UsedRange
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each oSheet In Sh.Parent.Worksheets
        If oSheet.Name <> Sh.Name Then
            oSheet.Range(oUsedRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, False)).Formula = oUsedRange.Formula
        End If
    Next oSheet
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Of course, this code only duplicates the cells' content - formatting or filtering options or images, for example, will not be copied over.

Comment: The solution is great but not sure what i'm doing wrong as nothing is happening.

Comment: In which module did you put the procedure code? This should be in the ThisWorkbook module (not the sheet modules, not the code modules - it's in the ThisWorkbook module) - https://www.excelcampus.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/5-Modules-to-Store-VBA-Macro-Code-in-a-Project-Workbook2.png

Comment: Apologies, i manage to include it just forgot to set the workbook as macro enabled..... that's great thanks. I'm gonna see if I can keep the formatting and conditional formatting but greatly appreciate your input!

Comment: Hi @JohnSUN thanks again for your help. I have an issue that when I filter other sheet (let's say September to reflect only september, then when I make changes everything move around and gets mixed up. any idea how I can keep one sheet to show only a specific month?

Comment: @HopeLessUser I'm afraid this problem has no easy solution. It was to be expected that applying a filter (hiding individual rows) could break the logic of copying to all sheets. It may be possible to get around the problem by remembering the filtering settings of each sheet, deleting them before copying and restoring them later. But this will complicate the macro code and make it even more unreliable. It's easier to refuse users to realize their desire - the tool (Excel) does not support this mode of operation. Sorry

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated, I though so to. I will just have to put my foot done.